# Using declarativeContent permission, hide pageAction after content change using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome Extension to add functionality to a site developed by others. I have no control over their code.

My code is only designed to work on specific pages of their site. Because the content is sensitive, I'm using the `chrome.declarativeContent` API to make sure I don't generate any permission warnings when my extension is installed that might spook my potential users.

The issue I have is the site author <strike>sometimes uses jQuery to overwrite part of the content on the page</strike> uses jQuery Mobile. This event does change the URL. The Chrome Extension API isn't responding to this change and leaving the `pageAction` icon displayed and the content script active.

The result is, each time I navigate back to a page that matches my `PageStateMatcher`, Chrome adds another instance of my content script to the page. When a user clicks my `pageAction` icon, the script fires multiple times, creating unwanted results.

### How can I clear the `pageAction` icon and content script after a jQuery change of content?

Code:

=== background.js===

```
var match_rules = {
    conditions: [
       new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
           //find pages like 'https://*.example.com/*/reports/report.asp'
           pageUrl: { 
               hostSuffix: '.example.com', 
               pathSuffix: '/reports/report.asp', 
            schemes: ['https']
            }
       })
    ],
    //If found, display the Page Action icon registered in the manifest.json
    actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([match_rules]);
    });
});

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'content_script.js'},  function(result){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: 'go'}, 
            function(response){
                console.log(response);
        });
  });
});
```

=== content_script.js ===

```
if (window == top) {
  chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, sendMessage) {
    console.log("Got request");
    doStuff();
    sendMessage('Done!');
  });
}
```

=== manifest.json ===

```
{
    "name": "My Extension",
    "permissions": [
       "declarativeContent", "activeTab"
    ],
    "background": {
       "scripts": ["background.js"],
       "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
       "default_icon": {
          "19": "images/logo_19.png",
          "38": "images/logo_38.png"
       },
       "default_title": "Do Something"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, and it's simpler than I thought.

The `declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher` does not trigger changes to `pageURL` rules that are done by updating `location.hash`.

Changes to `css` rules trigger the `PageStateMatcher` immediately when the DOM is modified.

In my case, only the page I was interested in acting upon had an element `#report`, so changing the conditions to:

```
       new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: { hostSuffix: '.example.com',  schemes: ['https'] },
          css: ["#report"]
       })
```

solved my problem.